Postgresql information_schema tables collation
I created a database with russian collation
CREATE DATABASE prj TEMPLATE template0
ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE "ru_RU.utf8" LC_CTYPE "ru_RU.utf8";                    

But the collation of information_schema.COLUMNS table does not work properly when I select column names from it
select lower(COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS




lower




Признак ВЗЛ (k1.6-e)


Уникальный номер договора (Д_b)


Срок нарушения (К2.1-К)


Срок заключения договора (К2.1-l)



And the length of table column name is ONLY 33 symbols
I expect that result could be in that case when collation specified in lower function
select lower(COLUMN_NAME  COLLATE "ru_RU.utf8")




lower




признак взл (k1.6-e)


уникальный номер договора (д_b)


срок нарушения (к2.1-к)


срок заключения договора (к2.1-l)



The main problem that lower() function does not work with russian letters in information_schema tables. All other tables in database work properly.
Another problem that the length of table column name is ONLY 33 symbols despite of that table names, column names, constraint names, etc. -- are limited to a maximum length of 63 bytes.

I would argue with this: ... length of table column name is ONLY 33 symbols. I have columns names up to 43 characters showing in information_schema.columns. Also the identifier length is a max of 63 bytes, but string columns store by character length where the byte per character can differ per encoding. I could replicate this issue. I would suggest posting here pgsql-ru-general or filing an issue here Bug report.

Adrian, you are right, length of column name depends of every symbol encoding.
I've just tested it by next piece of code:

create table t1
(
"englishaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" varchar(1000),
"русскийййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййййй" varchar(1000)
)
;
select length(column_name) from information_schema.columns
where table_name like 't1'

length|
------+
63|
31|

A possible solution is to pg_dump the database,
initdb --locale=ru_RU;
and then pg_restore the database.
This was Dawid Kuroczko's answer to a similar question at the Postgres discussion site, see: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200501262233.26378.vladimir%40sycore.org

Does initdb affects all databases on server?

@AlexTank this appears to be a general command for Postgres, as per, creating a new database cluster. So it makes sense to back up all your databases, import them into a copy where you experiment, run this command and see whether it's working as you expect it to work.

initdb sets the encoding for the template databases which means databases created from them will pick up that encoding unless overridden. The caveat being that you must use template0 if you want to change the encoding. See Template databases.

The post referred to is from 2005 and dealing with Postgres 8.0, which is 14 years past EOL. For 8.0 from here Multibyte encodings: Since these locale settings are frozen by initdb, the apparent flexibility to use different encodings in different databases of a cluster is more theoretical than real. It is likely that these mechanisms will be revisited in future versions of PostgreSQL. They where and you can use an encoding  that is different from the initdb setting in a given database.

Adrian, now I talk about db, where system catalog data store.
